# Can't buy bitcoins from Greece via prepaid card

Tags: buy-bitcoins, europe

I have an account at National Bank of Greece and would like to buy bitcoins in Greece using a pre-paid Visa Card. Can someone point out how I could do that? I could also get one from another bank if that's necessary. I have heard about a Bitcoin ATM somewhere, but I'm unsure if that would work in my case.

I also tried blockchain, but the bank didn't send the cash.

Comment: Bitcoin Core is a full node and includes wallet features. You cannot buy and sell Bitcoin directly in Bitcoin Core, you can only send/receive BTC. To buy/sell Bitcoin you need an exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot buy bitcoin from a greek bank account, transfer, with credit/debit card or using paypal. They have blocked all transactions due to the capital controls.

Comment: Seriously? What a mess

Answer (score 0):

You can buy Bitcoin via credit card / paypal via [https://xcoins.io](https://xcoins.io/?r=6377u7)

Disclaimer: I do work for them as an Software Engineer in our Santa Monica office.

Answer (score 0):

Using a prepaid card (if it's anonymous) is not something widely accepted, because it's not possible to see who's the sender. That's one of the main reasons to have some struggles.

If you have a bank account in Greece, you can easily buy Bitcoin using bank transfer (SEPA).

Answer (score 0):

Is it about buying coins anonymously? Then I would recommend to check out [bisq](https://bisq.network/), a decentralized exchange where you trade peer to peer via the means of your choice (SEPA and even cash in person I think). The best solution would buying for cash obviously, check out [this website](https://coinatmradar.com/) for checking if there is a Bitcoin-ATM around your place.

[Relai](https://relai.ch/) or [Pocket](https://pocketbitcoin.com/) are good solutions if KYC-light is an option for you. However I don't know if they are blacklisted by your bank.